# Firebase Messaging in Unity

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying Firebase Messaging in Unity, I follow the instruction from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client , but I got error when building

Error 1:

```
Error: Error while saving blame file, build will continue
Error: The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:overrideLibrary" associated with an element type "uses-sdk" is not bound.

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Error 2:

```
AndroidSDKToolsException: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.DetectErrorsAndWarnings (System.String logMessages, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.MergeManifests (System.String target, System.String mainManifest, System.String[] libraryManifests, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.MergeManifests (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, System.String targetManifest, System.String mainManifest)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: do you have the full error message in the console window ?

Comment: @lysergic-acid the error 1 and error 2 is the error i got from console window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:overrideLibrary" associated with an element type "uses-sdk" is not bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516305/error-the-prefix-tools-for-attribute-toolsoverridelibrary-associated-with)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found on unity issue tracker:

just open https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
scroll down to the bottom of that page
go to downloads
scroll down to the bottom of that page
find Windows "tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip" download and unzip it
find MacOSX "tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip" download and unzip it.
In the SDK path replace the tools folder.

Comment: i cant see any tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip

Comment: not sure this is the same issue. hard to tell from the error message.

Comment: Thank you! It work for me!! you can just download the newest android command line tool ,then replace SDK tools folder.